# Cannot mknod tun file, /dev/net/tun inaccessible

Tags: fedora, openvpn, android

I have successfully chrooted Fedora among other distros in my Android but I've run in a problem I cannot overcome.

I am trying to use openvpn on a .ovpn file, however I am unable to open `/dev/net/tun` as I do not have permissions; presumably since my Android is not rooted, as I do not have this problem on my rooted phone.

Here is what I thought:

`mknod /home/user/tun c 10 200`

With this I could create a node as chroot and then use shoot `openvpn --dev` to use that one, however running the aforementioned command creates no node. I am not getting any errors, it just doesn't create a node. I cannot run `mknod` outside the chroot system as my Android is not rooted.

Are there any workarounds? Sorry if this is a trivial question, I am not very familiar with nodes. I tried other distros just for the sake of it but same error happens.

Thanks a million in advance.

Comment: I don't think you can just create another device node to make use of the tun driver. Neither is `/dev/net/tun` a tun interface. `--dev` is a way to specify the name that OpenVPN should *create* the tun (or tap) interface with.

Comment: Thanks a lot @TomYan for the answer. I tried `openvpn --dev tun0 ./myfile.ovpn                                                 Options error: Unrecognized option or missing or extra parameter(s) in [CMD-LINE]:1: dev (2.4.11)             Use --help for more information.`. If you have any other ideas let me know, otherwise I guess it may be slightly impossible.

Comment: I think you are required to use `--config path/to/ovpn`, because `path/to/ovpn` is now not the only argument. Either way, `--dev tun0` is not gonna help if openvpn can't open the "real" `/dev/net/tun` (that is, a device node that is actually bind to the `tun` kernel driver). (I'm not even sure if your `mknod` actually made a real character file at all, since it shouldn't be possible when the device is not rooted.) TL;DR, don't bother, it won't work. Use a proper Android OpenVPN client.

Comment: Android OpenVPN client works fine, wanted to see if I could only tunnel the distro though. Anyways, thanks.